# Query from multiple tables in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to query from multiple tables in one query.

Although my code is working for one table, I don't know how to search in the second table too.

```
using (DataTable dt = new DataTable("Uniclass2015_EF_v1_12; Uniclass2015_En_v1_26")) 
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand (" select *from Uniclass2015_En_v1_26  where title like @Title; select *from Uniclass2015_EF_v1_12  where title like @Title", conn))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("code", txtSearch.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Title", string.Format("%{0}%", txtSearch.Text));

        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        adapter.Fill(dt);

        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    }
}

conn.Close();

private void txtSearch_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == (char)13)    // enter
        BtnSearch.PerformClick();
}
```

I tried to add a second table to my original code, but however when I type in the search box my query I receive a blank answer.

Comment: Might be a good idea to read about the "fun" the AddWithValue method can bring. https://sqlblog.org/addwithvalue

Comment: `DataTable dt = new DataTable("Uniclass2015_EF_v1_12; Uniclass2015_En_v1_26")` is (if I am correct) not correct, because you should specify 1 tablename between those `""`

Comment: @Luuk there is nothing syntactically wrong with that code. It will create a new DataTable with a very oddball name. It will not create two DataTables which is what the OP was thinking they wanted.

Comment: @SeanLange: OK, I had not time to test it, and missing experience on this point meself.  Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2):

looks like you're wanting to use the UNION operator in SQL:

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp

```
SELECT * FROM Uniclass2015_En_v1_26  WHERE title LIKE @Title UNION
 SELECT * FROM Uniclass2015_EF_v1_12  WHERE title LIKE @Title
```

This of course assumes the columns of the two tables are the same.  If you only need specific columns from each, just select those columns.

Also, I don't see where you're using that `code` parameter you're adding

Comment: It is worth mentioning that `UNION` will remove for duplicates which can be a performance challenge. However, in this case that is probably what they want. If the OP wants duplicates they would instead use `UNION ALL`.